# Bed frame not stable

Tags: bedroom, furniture, wood

I have a wooden bed frame that uses wooden bolt thingies to attach each part together. However, instead of 3 bolts each for connection, I only have 2, so the bed shakes a lot and sometimes breaks apart in the middle of the night. What I have done is put a large enough crate (beer crate) in between the frame and the wall, but it is temporary. What can I do to make the bed more stable?

P. S. I do not have any tools since I am an exchange student in Germany for a short time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Place the bed firmly against the wall and place anything heavy like a a set of drawers to the foot end of the bed.
2. If you are able to buy a cheap hammer and some nails, get some very long ones and hammer them in around the joints.
3. I'm assuming you mean wooden dowels are being used, reinforce them by pulling them out of the holes, stuffing newspaper in the hole and use super glue (if you have any) to bind the dowels into the holes.
4. Using 4 pieces of rope, tie the bottom of the left legs, from the head to the foot end to each other..very tightly, do the same for the right. If you have one of the wooden beds where the headboard has vertical slats, tie another piece of rope from each corner of the headboard, tuck down to the legs of the head end, run along the base and tie to the foot end.

Hope that makes sense. Any questions let me know and Good Luck! :-)

Comment: Great answer; upvote. Just one clarification: Instead of super glue, a wood glue will work better.